# "In my job" vs. "at my job"

Tags: prepositions, difference

Could you tell which preposition: *in* or *at* it is correct and natural to use in the following sentences?

> The thing is, I didn't like the working hours **in**/**at** my previous job, which is why I quit.
>
> I have a lot on my plate **in**/**at** my job at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would only use *at my job* in two contexts:

1. Where it is referring to a way or quality of doing the job:

> I'm not very good at my job.

> He's very clever at his job.

> They're methodical at their jobs.

2. Where it is referring metonymically to the place where I work.

> There's somebody at my job who keeps annoying me.

(This use is not very common - more often people say *at work* or *at my office*, or *at the shop* -  but you hear it sometimes).

So in both your examples *at my job* is possible, in the second sense; but *in my job* is much more likely. In the first case, I'd say that *of* or *for* is more likely still.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! I am confused though. Could you clear things up please? You said "in my job" is more likely. More likely in which case? For talking about working hours or workload. And how is "of" and "for" are relevent? Could you tell me what you mean by saying "of" and "for" is more likely still?

Comment: I said that _in my job_ is more likely than _at my job_ in both cases: only if the speaker was using "my job" metonymically to mean "my place of work" is _at_ possible, in either sentence. But I added that _the working hours of my job_ or _for my job_ seemed to me more likely still.

Answer (score 0):

I have to disagree with the explanation in the first example. We say "I am good/methodical at my job" because this preposition is required by the adjective:

> I am good at something.
> I am terrible at something.